# How to understand sequenced-before and reorder?

Tags: c++, c++11

[Sequenced-before](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) is defined in C++ standard that

> If A is sequenced before B, then evaluation of A will be complete before evaluation of B begins

And there is a long list of rules about when A is sequenced-before B.

However, from this list I find a full expression is sequenced before the next full expression. Since an entire expression statement is a full expression, so in the following codes, 3/4/5 are full expressions while 1/2 are not(they are declaration statements).

```
int main(){
    int a = 1; // 1
    int b = 2; // 2
    a = 10; // 3 
    b = 20; // 4
    printf("%d %d", a, b); // 5
}
```

So, according to definition of sequenced-before, can compiler/CPU reorder 3/4?

I have two answers:

1. No, they can't

   This is because 3 is sequenced-before 4, so 3 must be executed before 4.
2. Yes, the can

   According to the [as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if), C++ allows any and all code transformations that do not change the observable behavior of the program.
   Since the order of 3 and 4 does not matter, so compiler/CPU have every reason to reorder, according to as-if rule.

Seems I get a contradiction here.

UPDATE

How about

```
int main(){
    int a = 1; // 1
    int b = 2; // 2
    a = random_int(); // 3 
    b = random_int(); // 4
    printf("%d %d", a, b); // 5
}
```

Comment: Thanks to the as-if rule, your entire function can be optimized to `printf("%d %d", 10, 20);` and none of the previous lines will even exist in the binary.  Lets say you assign something to `a` after the `printf` call, that can happen before, as that would change the output that you see.  That isn't the case though with any of your code.  reordering the operations wont change the end behavior.

Comment: What if I make 10 and 20 to some random functions?

Comment: From the linked page: "a full expression is: [...] an entire initializer, including any comma-separated constituent expressions", so `= 1` and `= 2` (on lines 1 and 2) are full expression (not relevant to your main question though)

Comment: Unless the compiler knows what those functions return, then it will not be able to optimize it like that.

Comment: @Artyer Why in [this section](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/statements#Expression_statements), `int n = 1` is a declaration statement rather than expression statement?

Comment: @calvin A full expression doesn't have to be an expression statement

Comment: Regarding your new example, 3 and 4 can be reordered as they do not depend on each other, but they have to happen before 5.

Comment: @NathanOliver Though 3 does not carry dependency into 4, I think it sequenced before 4.

Comment: 1) and 2) are init-statements, which are full expressions. In the code in the question; any reordering that preserves the output is okay. The primary purpose of "sequenced before" is to deal with inter-thread relationships, where the "as-if" rule needs more detailed specifiaction, because there are multiple possible sequences of valid results.

Comment: "As-if" allows for any transformation that would not change the observable behavior. If "as-if" allows a change that would be forbidden by another rule, then the change is allowed because by definition the change is not observable. There is no contradiction.

Comment: @calvin It is sequenced before as far as the standard is concerned, but thanks to the as-if rule, the compiler can swap them around as it does not change the observable behavior of the program.

Comment: @NathanOliver According to your comments, can I understand that 3 is sequenced before 4. However as-if rule can override the "sequenced before rule", if it does not change the observable behavior?

Comment: Yep, that is the definition of the as-if rule.  The compiler can change the code around how it likes, as long as doing so still produces the exact same output the program out have if ran through the C++ abstract machine, i.e, follow that standard.

Comment: @calvin It's better to think of the "as-if" rule living at the boundary between the abstract C++ machine and the concrete x86 (or whichever) machine the compiler is targeting, and not actually being a C++ rule.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux the as-if rule is in the standard: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/intro#abstract-1

Comment: @calvin The "as-if" rule is part of the definition of observable behavior. The sequencing rules are part of the core language definitions that define what the code will do in terms of observable behavior. As long as the generated assembly's result matches that required observable behavior then the compiler is allowed to produce it. If there are multiple equivalent assemblies possible the compiler can produce any of those that it wants, which is where the "as-if" rule comes from and why it can "override" other rules.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks, I always thought it was an emergent rule, codified by non-standard references for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

A compiler may only re-order 3 and 4 if you can't observe that reordering.

[Here's](https://godbolt.org/z/bGaf9bTYz) an example of one (arguably) doing so

The resulting object code enregisters the 20 before the 10

```
.LC0:
        .string "%d %d"
main:
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     edx, 20
        mov     esi, 10
        xor     eax, eax
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        call    printf
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
```

An alternative explanation is that this isn't a reordering, those expression are *gone*. Notice how there's no mention of `1` or `2` anymore.

Comment: Since it actually can, I wonder how to explain that

Comment: @calvin because an x86 machine is not an instance of the C++ abstract machine. And for all we know the CPU might re-order it back in hardware

Comment: @calvin In this specific case there is an reason for the reordering. The [cdecl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl) calling convention pushes the last argument first on the stack (if the stack is involved). Thus if reordering is possible it could help to optimization the code a little bit. If you extend Caleths example with more numbers, you will see the ordering [going nuts all over the place](https://godbolt.org/z/5W7TrY1Yj) while still somewhat backwards...

Answer (score 0):

**You don't need to worry about reordering**, at least as long as your program is single-threaded.

The seqenced-before relation determines what behavior you're going to *see*.

The compiler can then reorder whatever it wants, as long as observable behavior conforms to sequenced-before.

---

> How about `random_int()`?

It doesn't matter what functions you call, reordering isn't going to affect the observable behavior.

---

> Since an entire expression statement is a full expression, so in the following codes, 3/4/5 are full expressions while 1/2 are not(they are declaration statements).

If we're splitting hairs, none of them are full-expressions. :P

In

```
int a = 1; // 1
int b = 2; // 2
a = 10; // 3 
b = 20; // 4
printf("%d %d", a, b); // 5
```

Full-expressions are: `1`, `2` (the initializers), `a = 10`, `b = 20`, `printf("%d %d", a, b)`.

`a = 10;` (with `;`) is an expression-statement, but not an expression. If you remove the `;`, it turns into a full-expression.